# How to make a popup while windows session is locked (prefer Windows BATCH file)

Tags: batch-file, remote-access, psexec, local-security-policy

I am Help Desk for a company and we have some computers on our VPN.  We sometimes have to use Windows Remote Desktop to login to these computers. (mostly Windows XP but some Windows 7)

When we remote into a Windows the computer/session is locked

I would like to be able to make a popup appear on their computer saying they can log back in.

I use 2 command-line tools in order to issue remote commands: *psexec* & *nircmd*.

*nircmd* is useful because it has command-line options to make a pop-up but it will pop-up inside the session not on the "computer locked screen".

I have played with Local Security Policy and it will you to display a message when they first login but not while the session is locked.

It does have an option to display username while session is locked so somehow it can display certain things during a locked session.

Comment: have you checked `msg.exe`   ->  `c:\> msg /?`

Comment: Wow, thank you.

msg.exe will do this!

Comment: Did you find a solution? If so, could you please post it and mark it as the Answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@npocmaka Thanks

I ended up using msg.exe but because of restrictions on our company's network I used a combination of psexec and msg

> msg server:IPADDRESS /v "message"

didn't work so I used

> psexec \IPADDRESS -u username -p password msg /server:IPADDRESS /v  "message"

but in order for it to work I had to run

> psexec \IPADDRESS -u username -p password reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server" /v AllowRemoteRPC /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f

on the remote computer. I got the reg command from another post in StackOverflow actually!